# Rspec - uninitialized constant Rails (NameError )

Tags: rspec

I am trying to use a Rails engine in my rails application.

The rails engine uses a gem called `spin.js`.

In my rails app, I have in my `spec_helper` file, this code to include the engine (which is a gem).

```
require 'mycustomEngine'
```

When I run rspec I get this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spinjs-rails-1.4/lib/spinjs
-rails/engine.rb:2:in `<module:Spinjs>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError
)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spinjs-rails-1
.4/lib/spinjs-rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/spinjs-rails-1
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you solve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you have your rails_helper / spec_helper configured, you might be requiring the engine (or some other dependency) that tries to access the `Rails` constant, which doesn't get loaded until you get to the line `require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)`. Try requiring it after that?